# How to use class in Ruby extension written in C defined in other C file?

Tags: c, ruby-c-extension

I create an extension for Ruby in C and I am currently struggling with calling constructor on class I defined also in C.

Code for class definition is called before the class is being used.
I am trying to get the class using

```
VALUE rb_cConfidenceInterval = rb_const_get( rb_cObject, rb_intern( "ConfidenceInterval" ) );
VALUE interval = rb_funcall(
        rb_cConfidenceInterval, rb_intern( "new" ), 2,
        rb_float_new( lower_bound ),
        rb_float_new( upper_bound )
);
```

but it fails while running tests on `uninitialized constant ConfidenceInterval`. `NormalDistribution::ConfidenceInterval` did not help either.

To provide some context, the code is available on [github](https://github.com/domcermak/normal_distribution/tree/1-simplify-confidence-interval)

Any idea how to get the class?

I was trying to find something like `require`, but it does not seem to be anything like it.

Answer (score 0):

```
VALUE rb_cConfidenceInterval = rb_path2class( "NormalDistribution::ConfidenceInterval" );
```

based on [examples](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/rb_require/cpp-rb_require-function-examples.html)